# Mysql Database Stored Procedure Return after Drop

Tags: mysql, dbforge

Yesterday I **dropped the stored procedure permanently from the database** today I found it in place?

I use **DBForge**?

Comment: Something must have added back.

Comment: Like What? @Barmar

Comment: No idea, maybe a cron job?

Comment: This cannot be an effect of non-committed transaction - dropping the procedure causes immediate commit. So something have restored this SP. This can be some service procedure executed from event scheduler or external scheduler (cron) which detects SP absence and restores it from backup, or an effect of some software which do the same check and restoring.

Comment: Or you just have thought you deleted the stored procedure, but in reality you did not. There is really no way for us to tell.